# What is the cause of Wingtip Stalling? Why do sweptback wings have a tendency of stalling at the tip?

Tags: aerodynamics

I am a beginner in Aircraft aerodynamics. I have read about the disadvantages of wingtip stalling and the fact that sweptback wings have a greater tendency of stalling at the tips and forward swept wings don't. However, I don't know what causes it to happen. Is it something to do with the direction of airflow from root to tip and vice versa?